# Why can't I set a width to this UL element in my HTML?

Tags: html, css

Go [HERE](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com), and you will notice that the "Audio" tile's player can be seen on both tiles when I need it only to be seen on the tile that says Audio. When it slides, I mean. I tried setting a width to the UL element that the tiles are in but that screws it up. I'm at a loss. I have tried everything I can think of. Any input?

CSS

```
#audioTile {
padding:5px;
}

#audioTile ul, #audioTile li {
width:115px;
height:105px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
list-style:none;
}
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#audioTile").easySlider({
            auto: true, 
            continuous: true,
                            controlsShow: false
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="trigger" id="audioTile"> <ul>
<li>    <h5>Audio</h5>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{MonthNumber} {DayOfMonth} {Year}
<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{block:NoteCount}{NoteCount} <img   
src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/2Z0lf9580/heart.png">{/block:NoteCount}
<div class="player1">{AudioPlayerWhite}</div>
</li>
<li> hey big fat weirdo loL!
</li>  </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post some code, thanks.

Comment: Or at least pare down your problem to a reproducible test case, instead of an entire site.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is your friend, post there and share link

Comment: Also, using &nbsp;'s for style is a very bad start....

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you didn't set overflow:hidden on your ul and you are scrolling with your js... since you set list-style:none, and explicitly set the li 's width.( by default, overflow is allowed)

---

ps, firebug suggests to me that you have included two players in the same tile... not sure if that's what you want...